# macOS self hosted build agent failing to start when run as launchd service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm attempting to follow the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops#run-as-a-launchd-service) to run a self hosted build agent on a mac with launchd but the agent remains as offline in Azure Devops

This is what is returned from running `./svc.sh status`

```
status vsts.agent.boomin.MacOS.macOS-11:

/Users/administrator/Library/LaunchAgents/vsts.agent.boomin.MacOS.macOS-11.plist

Started:
- 126 vsts.agent.boomin.MacOS.macOS-11
```

In the portal it still says offline...

[image]

When I initially ran the `./svc.sh start` command, it showed this...

```
starting vsts.agent.boomin.MacOS.macOS-11
status vsts.agent.boomin.MacOS.macOS-11:

/Users/administrator/Library/LaunchAgents/vsts.agent.boomin.MacOS.macOS-11.plist

Started:
7356 0 vsts.agent.boomin.MacOS.macOS-11
```

But then almost immediately after when running `./svc.sh status` it changes to `126`

I'm on macOS Big Sur.

What could be the issue here?